# Subscription on relay graphql query for chat utility

Tags: react-native, graphql, react-native-gifted-chat, react-relay

I'm trying to create a chat using relay graphql and react-native-gifted-chat. The problem I have is refreshing the query with each message both from me and other participants. The query already includes pagination, but I don't really know how to handle subscriptions. Is `useSubscribeToInvalidationState` good for this case, or would you recommend something else? Do you have any useful examples for that?

Comment: Do you mean that you have to manually refresh to see the new messages?

Comment: It wasn't mentioned in the docs, but in the end using edges and inserting new messages with insertEdgeAfter was the right thing